# Cordova plugin embedded framework dependency

Tags: javascript, swift, cordova, cocoapods, progressive-web-apps

Developing a commercial app based on VueJS and Cordova. (https://cordova.apache.org)

Implementing a payment checkout based on the following SDK's:

https://github.com/MultiSafepay/fastcheckout-ios-sdk
and
https://github.com/MultiSafepay/fastcheckout-android-sdk

The PDF in the repo describes how to do it but my situation with cordova is different from the React Native scenario described there.

My approach is to reference the SDK from a Cordova plugin:
https://github.com/chipbizz/cbz-msp-checkout

The plugin works in terms of cordova exec so that's good but I am unable to import the FastcheckoutKit into the Swift code.

I've spent days and nights already but no luck.
Is anyone able to see which of Cordova's many methods for including should be used? CocoaPod? Framework tag? Source file tag? Etc.. I've tried them all but no luck.